# Will it be safe to jailbreak my iPhone 3Gs?

Tags: jailbreak, iphone, cydia

Currently I have an 8 GB iPhone 3Gs (A1303). It has become slightly slower so I am wishing to jailbreak it. Will it be safe? If yes give me specific sites which will help me jailbreak it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Safe' is a broad term. If you keep a backup though, there's not much that can go wrong as you can always restore that backup. In addition, as there are no updates available for the 3Gs, you can safely restore to a jailbreakable version of iOS if anything goes wrong.

As the last version of iOS that can be installed on the iPhone 3Gs is iOS 6.1.6, this can be jailbroken using [p0sixspwn](http://p0sixspwn.com). Download it, then follow the instructions.

Comment: Thank you, it is very helpful. Btw i am not very used to backup... Will it backup all my contacts and text messages?? As well as i have few very important notes will it backup these all things?

Comment: @dking iCloud backup will back up all your content including all app data, except the apps themselves, as they are re-downloaded from the App Store when restoring the backup. iTunes backup will back up everything on the device similar to iCloud backup, except apps which will be downloaded from your transferred purchases in iTunes.

Comment: Thank you george it clears all my doubts. I will try jailbreaking my cell as soon as possible. Will it improve my cell phones performance?

Comment: @dking That depends what you do. Installing tweaks may reduce performance, but uninstalling system components/apps that you don't use can improve performance.